# Why I did not get the right result in this c++ code ( see the f3.show_fraction() in main )?

Tags: c++

I did not get right result for object f3 when I see the f3 using show_fraction() function in
the below code: I am confused. I want to access the sum of f1 and f2 fraction that is stored in f3.But when i see the result in f3 it shows 0/0 in result using fraction_show() function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class fraction
{
private:
    float numerator;
    float denominator;
    char ch;

public:
    void get_fraction()
    {
        cout << "\nEnter the fraction ( in format n/d ): ";
        cin >> numerator >> ch >> denominator;
    }

    void show_fraction()
    {
        cout << " Fraction is: " << numerator << "/" << denominator;
    }

    fraction sum(fraction &f, fraction &d) // returns sum of two fractions
    {
        fraction ff; // to hold the result
        // denominator of result
        ff.numerator = (f.numerator * d.denominator + f.denominator * d.numerator);
        ff.denominator = f.denominator * d.denominator; // numerator of result
        return ff;
    }
};

int main() // program to test the class
{
    fraction f1, f2, f3; // three objects of type fraction created
    char ch1;

    do
    {
        f1.get_fraction();
        f2.get_fraction();
        f3.sum(f1, f2);
        cout << "\nSum of ";
        f3.show_fraction();                            // shows the result ( wrong result)
        cout << "\nDo you want to continue ( y/n ): "; // If the user want to continue
        cin >> ch1;

    } while (ch1 != 'n');

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
} // end of main
```

Comment: I agree with @user17732522 - you're not assigning the result of the sum to anything, you're just calling the method f3.sum.

Comment: You call `sum` on `f3`, but `sum` makes _another_ `fraction` called `ff` and stores the result in there instead of into `f3` (the instance on which `sum` was called). You then _return_ that `ff`, but never use the return value from it in `main`. So after the call `f3` doesn't have the result and the newly created `ff` with the result is gone unused. Compare to `get_fraction` and `show_fraction` where you operate on the members of the instance that the function was called on instead of making a new one, which is probably what you want `sum` to do as well.

Comment: Do you write `(7).plus(5,3)`? If you do, does 7 become 8?

Comment: Thanks for solving my confusion @user17732522 and @
FreudianSlip  Actually I am a beginner so I have lots of question while learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like this style of coding, but at least this works

```
void sum(fraction &f, fraction &d) // calculates sum of two fractions
{
    numerator = (f.numerator * d.denominator + f.denominator * d.numerator);
    denominator = f.denominator * d.denominator;
}
```

then

```
f3.sum(f1, f2);
```

I would prefer something like this

```
friend fraction sum(fraction &f, fraction &d) // returns sum of two fractions
{
    fraction ff; // to hold the result
    // denominator of result
    ff.numerator = (f.numerator * d.denominator + f.denominator * d.numerator);
    ff.denominator = f.denominator * d.denominator; // numerator of result
    return ff;
}
```

with this version you need to change the way you call the function

```
f3 = sum(f1, f2);
```

I'm not sure which you were intending but you wrote something that was half way between the two versions.